# Binary to decimal (and back) converter in c++

Tags: c++, error-handling, converting, type-safety

I'm mainly looking for error checking / type safety advice.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

void binaryToDecimal();
void decimalToBinary();

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    bool running = true;
    int ans;

    while (running)
    {
        std::cout << "1. Binary to decimal\n2. Decimal to binary\n3. Quit\n";
        std::cin >> ans;
            
        std::cout << '\n';

        switch (ans)
        {
        case 1:
            binaryToDecimal();
            break;

        case 2:
            decimalToBinary();
            break;

        case 3:
            running = false;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void binaryToDecimal()
{
    int out = 0;
    std::string in;

    std::cout << "Input binary number: ";
    std::cin >> in;

    int i = in.size() - 1;
    if (i > 32)
    {
        std::cerr << "That number is too big!\n\n";
        return;
    }

    for (int j = 0; i > -1; --i, ++j)
    {
        out += static_cast<int>(std::pow(2, i)) * (in[j] - '0');
    }

    std::cout << in << " when converted to decimal is " << out << "\n\n";
}

void decimalToBinary()
{
    std::string out = "";
    std::string in;
    std::cout << "Input decimal number: ";
    std::cin >> in;

    if (in.size() > std::to_string(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()).size())
    {
        std::cerr << "That number is too big!\n\n";
        return;
    }

    int mod = std::stoi(in);

    while (mod > 0)
    {
        out += (mod % 2) + '0';
        mod /= 2;
    }
    std::reverse(out.begin(), out.end());

    std::cout << in << " when converted to binary is " << out << "\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### General Observations

> I'm mainly looking for error checking / type safety advice.

There doesn't seem to be a lot of error checking on user input and user input is one of the places where error checking is most important. For instance, the code doesn't handle negative numbers but there is not checking for negative input.

The code also doesn't check for lack of input, and there are no error messages when the input is wrong.

### Type Safety

Since the program doesn't process negative numbers it might be better to use `unsigned` or `unsigned int` for conversion rather than `int`.

### Unnecessary Function Prototypes

If the `main()` function were placed at the bottom of the file rather than the top of the file, the function prototypes

```
void binaryToDecimal();
void decimalToBinary();
```

are not needed.

### Magic Numbers

There is a Magic Numbers in the `binaryToDecimal()` function (32), it might be better to create symbolic constants for them to make the code more readable and easier to maintain. These numbers may be used in many places and being able to change them by editing only one line makes maintenance easier.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them. There is a discussion of this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

In this case `32` probably refers to word size, but that is an arbitrary number, most computers these days have a 64 bit word size. You could get the actual size of the word by using the `sizeof()` function and then multiplying it by 8 since `sizeof()` the number of char in the object and 8 bits is the size of a char, there also might be a word size constant hidden in an include header.

### Complexity

While `main()` is pretty simple now, once you start adding the error checking you need it will get more complex, and it should be broken up into different function.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits()` might be a good choice for the maximum number of bits. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits

Comment: None of the answers to [the Q&A you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7349689) mention anything about using a `union` of a natural integer and `std::bitset`. And I would advise *strongly* against it. It isn't going to do what you hope...

Comment: @CodyGray Removed that paragraph.

Comment: I would dispute "Unnecessary Function Prototypes" under Robert Martins step down rule. Humans like to read stories in order.

Comment: @candied_orange I think of `main()` as a special case because it is the operating system entry point. The use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program. The functions that `main()` calls are more important than `main()` itself. `main()` is the final chapter in a mystery that ties all the ends together.

Comment: @pacmaninbw no. That’s even worse. If you’re not going to take advantage of modern language tools like forward declaration to enable human readable step down ordering then at least stay consistent with the previous paradigm.

Comment: @candied_orange If you want to discuss this further join me in the [2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Answer (score 4):

## Handling invalid input

Not handling invalid input can be dangerous, especially in this case since it can cause strange outputs. A good practice is to validate the input before you perform any calculations / process it. Here's an example, imagine you opened *command prompt* on your laptop and entered a false statement. 
This would show you `unknown command x`, Instead, what if it started to spit out random numbers endlessly, and crashed in 2-3 seconds? You don't want this to happen with your programs either.

## Use `enum`s or `enum class`s

@pacmaninbw has already written in his review the larger downsides of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). But how do you avoid this? Use an [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum). The syntax is simple, and makes your code more readable for others.

```cpp
enum Choices
{    bin_to_dec = 1, dec_to_bin, quit };
```

This will automatically set `dec_to_bin` to `2`, and `quit` to `3`.

Now your `switch` statement is clear;

```cpp
switch ( ans ) 
{
case bin_to_dec:
     ....

case dec_to_bin:
    ....

case quit:
    ...

default:
   ...
}
```

## Logic

There is a much simpler way to convert decimal to binary in C++. All you have to do is to use [**std::bitset**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

It would simplify the implementation greatly

### Decimal to binary

Here is an example

```cpp
void dec_to_bin()
{
    int number = 736;
    std::cout << (std::bitset<32>)number;
}
```

I have used `32` since that is the max size of `signed int`.

Output:

> 00000000000000000000001011100000

[Yes it's the correct answer](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=055051054)

You can even use its `to_string()` method to get a string representation, which might be useful to remove the extra `0`'s.

```cpp
binary.erase(0, binary.find_first_not_of('0')); 
std::cout << binary;
```

> 1011100000

### Binary to decimal

The best part is, this works the other way around too, by using `.to_ulong()` assume you have the binary in a string like this.

```cpp
std::string binary = "1011100000"; // from our previous example, we know this is = 736

auto decimal = std::bitset<32>(binary).to_ulong();

std::cout << decimal;
```

> 736

Remember that validating input before doing this is a must.